# How to find the current Azure RM Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

In Azure Classic / Service Management, Get-AzureSubscription would give a list of subscriptions in the Tenant with an indicator of which was current.

There was also a `Get-AzureSubscription -Current` flag that would give you just the current subscription.

Is there a way to find the current subscription in AzureRM.Profile?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`Get-AzureRmContext` gives you info about the selected subscription, default storage account, etc.

`(Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription` gives you the current subscription.

Comment: Ha! it does, At some point in looking for the answer I looked at that as well. Guess I should stay off the stupid juice for a while... Thanks

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out after I upgraded to the AzureRM modules too.

Comment: It is 2024 and this is no longer available: WARNING: The command Get-AzureRmContext is in the AzureRM PowerShell module, which is outdated. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2202029 for instructions to migrate to Az. <br/> Use this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190044/5042393

Answer (score 11):

Now you can use the new Az commands

Get-AzContext

Comment: Hi Jucer, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide more context as to what information the `Get-AzContext` command provides, and possibly whether or not the accepted answer no longer applies? Your answer is fairly terse.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Get-AzureRmSubscription

```
$sub = Get-AzureRmSubscription
$sub.SubscriptionId
```

This will give you the SubscriptionId

Comment: If you have multiple subscriptions, this will return an array of both of them with no indication of which is currently selected. @BenV's answer works in both cases.

Comment: Agree with Trevor

Answer (score 1):

`Get-AzureRmContext` and `Get-AzContext` both are valid but `Get-AzContext` is latest way to do it

> You might have seen or used Azure PowerShell commands that used an
> -AzureRM format. In December 2018 Microsoft released for general availability the AzureRM module replacement with the Az module. This
> new module has several features, notably a shortened cmdlet noun
> prefix of -Az, which replaces AzureRM. The Az module ships with
> backwards compatibility for the AzureRM module, so the -AzureRM cmdlet
> format will work.